# Installer for Oracle Forms Builder application?

Tags: oracle

I have made a small project in Oracle, by using the oracle forms builder - how do I create an installer (`setup.exe`) for my project (one that would setup the application on MS Windows?)

Please... help me, and thanks a lot

Comment: I'm not sure that the edit improved the question - does Nader need to set an icon for his app, or create an installer (i.e. a "setup icon") for it?

Comment: Oh. By "to make a setup icon for my project" Nader must have meant an installer, not an icon..

Answer (score 3):

Up to Forms 6i you can have a Forms runtime client installed on the target PC. That target PC also needs connectivity to the database. You don't need a license for the runtime client.

From 6i onwards, the Forms component can run through an application server with the client accessing it through a Java applet in the browser. The app server needs connectivity to the database, but the end client doesn't. The app server needs appropriate Oracle licensing.

Forms 6i itself has the choice of running through an installed runtime client or through a web browser.

Forms cannot be implemented through a simple windows installer.

Answer (score 1):

What version of oracle forms are you using?
In my last job we used Forms v4.5 (Developer 2000) - and for that version (which is quite old now) the Forms Runtime software had to be installed on the client computers.
Then, when the user double clicked on an .FMX file the Forms runtime (F45run32.exe) would load and run the form.
Which is a long way of saying that for v4.5 you couldn't create a stand alone install.  (That may have changed with future versions)